# Laravel routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am using `laravel` framework. I've setup couple of `routes` that take a parameter like **`example.com/route/{dir_name}`**. When I pass in a dir which has childrens it considers it as another route. Is there a way to bypass it?

I'm using this code:

```
Route::get('/route/something/{path}',array('as'=>'something',function($path){
     return $path;
}));
```

When I use `/route/something/home/user/dev` it throws a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\ Exception\NotFoundHttpException` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using constraints on the route parameter with a regular expression.

```
Route::any('/route/{dir_name}', function ($dir_name) {
    return $dir_name;
})->where('dir_name', '.*');
```

See the docs section about [route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters), specifically the "Regular Expression Route Constraints" part.

Comment: Cool, glad to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You have **example.com/route/{dir_name}**

I assume your route defined in routes.php

```
Route::get('/route/{dir_name}', [
    'as' => 'someRoute',
    'uses' => 'SomeController@index'
]);
```

In your SomeController.php file you would have this method that takes in the {dir_name}

```
public function index($dir_name) {
return $dir_name;
}
```

Instead you have the Route

```
Route::get('/route/something/{path}',array('as'=>'something',function($path){
     return $path;
}));
```

/route/**something**/{path}

If you want **something** in your URL then it has to be in the Route. This is why you're getting the **NotFoundHttpException**

Comment: Paste your complete route file buddy. Let me see if i can help

Comment: i just want to pass some directories to my url like /route/{dir-here} but when laravel encounters a "/" in path, it considers it as a route so how should i stop it from doing that>

Comment: @arkhamDev, "something" doesn't have to be in the route, you can use route constraints to achieve this. Check my answer to see how.

Comment: @borfast thank you. I'll check route constraints out.